# plotting chi-square results with corrplot raises matrix error

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I'm trying to visualize the results of chisq.test with the corrplot package and I'm getting an error I don't understand.  Hope someone can enlighten me.

```
library(corrplot)

no <- c(330, 470, 75, 400, 1050, 170, 90)
yes <- c(1700, 1000, 250, 2100, 500, 1250, 1200)
df <- data.frame(no, yes)

#read in fn cor.mtest
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

p.mat <- cor.mtest(df)

chisq <- chisq.test(df)
M <- as.matrix(chisq$residuals)
corrplot(M, cl.pos = "b", p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.005, insig = "blank")
```

the error is:

```
Error in corrplot(M, cl.pos = "b", p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.005, insig = "blank") : 
The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
```

It does not seem to prevent the results plotting. I want to understand what it's trying to tell me here, but the documentation is not enlightening on this point. Can someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Try printing matrix `M`. The message is telling you it has at least one element outside the range [-1, 1], which means it’s not a correlation matrix.

Comment: thanks that actually does explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "M" is a correlation matrix, so if you set `is.corr = FALSE` you get output (although I'm not sure whether the output is correct or not; p.mat is only 4 values, but you have 14 values in M so you get a bunch of warnings):

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.90 loaded

no <- c(330, 470, 75, 400, 1050, 170, 90)
yes <- c(1700, 1000, 250, 2100, 500, 1250, 1200)
df <- data.frame(no, yes)

#read in fn cor.mtest
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}

p.mat <- cor.mtest(df)

chisq <- chisq.test(df)
M <- as.matrix(chisq$residuals)
corrplot(M, is.corr = FALSE, cl.pos = "b", p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.005, insig = "blank")
#> Warning in rownames(p.mat) == rownames(corr): longer object length is not a
#> multiple of shorter object length
#> Warning in corrplot(M, is.corr = FALSE, cl.pos = "b", p.mat = p.mat, sig.level
#> = 0.005, : p.mat and corr may be not paired, their rownames and colnames are not
#> totally same!
#> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 14, 4
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In my opinion, just plotting the residuals makes more sense:

```r
corrplot(M, is.corr = FALSE, cl.pos = "b", cl.length = 5, insig = "blank")
```

[image: example.png]